# Caller device doesn't receive callback when the call is established

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, video-streaming, sinch

I'm using Sinch SDK for video calls in my app. The app has a MainActivity.java which opens several fragments. The structure/flow of the app is like this:

- MainActiivty is the launcher/starting activity
- It opens LoginFragment. User inputs their credentials in the login fragment.
- Loginfragment authenticates information with my own server and generates a unique userName for Sinch Video SDK login.
- Login Fragment sends the unique userName to the MainActivity. The MainActivity executes the following code to login Sinch Video SDK

  ```
  getSinchServiceInterface().setStartListener(this);
  if (!getSinchServiceInterface().isStarted()) {
      getSinchServiceInterface().startClient(userName);
  }
  ```
- MainActivity.java opens ProfileFragment.java. In this fragment the user enters the name of the *callee* device.
- ProfileFragment.java sends *callee* userName to the MainActivity. The MainActivity executes the following code to call the *callee device*

  ```
  getSinchServiceInterface().callUserVideo(calleeUserName);
  ```
- After executing this, the caller device doesn't get any callback when the callee device picks up the call. So as a workaround, I'm monitoring the ***onLogMessage() in SinchService*** to look for *onSessionEstablished* tag.
- When the mentioned tag is received in onLogMessage in SinchService.java, I execute the following code.

  ```
  Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCalleeID);
  if (call != null) {
      if (!mAddedListener) {
          call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
          mAddedListener = true;
      }

      if (call.getState() == CallState.ESTABLISHED) {
          openVideoCallFragment(mCallId);
      }
  } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "Started with invalid callId, aborting.");
  }
  ```
- However upon execution of this method, it just gives the following log message:

  ```
     Started with invalid callId, aborting.
  ```

I'm not sure how can I fix it or how can I know when the callee device has pickedup the call.

**My MainActivity.java extends BaseActivity.java provided in the sample app of the Sinch SDK.**

Comment: Are you hooking up the callClient delegate anywhere? You can't really start a cal like that, it needs to come from the callClient

Comment: I'm not hooking the call client anywhere. The thing is IDK how to connect the call client because I have only 1 activity and the onServiceConnected is called only ONCE in that activity. Where should I put this code:

Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().getCall(mCalleeID);
if (call != null) {
    if (!mAddedListener) {
        call.addCallListener(new SinchCallListener());
        mAddedListener = true;
    }

    if (call.getState() == CallState.ESTABLISHED) {
        openVideoCallFragment(mCallId);
    }
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Started with invalid callId, aborting.");
}